# What’s the source for saying Parshyot Yirah and Teshuva daily?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, minhag, repentance-teshuvah, yirat-shamaim

In many Siddurim, after Shacharit the Parshas of Yirah and Teshuva, both from Sefer Devarim, are written. What is the source for this?

NB: Parshas HaMon is usually printed along with them, but I know the source for this is a Yerushalmi which we unfortunately do not have in our editions. However, I haven’t seen a source for the two I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is from the Rishonim. Rabbeinu Yonah in [Sefer HaYirah](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYirah.240?lang=bi) says:

> תמיד הרגל על שפתיך דברי יראת שמים כגון הוי עז כנמר. סוף דבר הכל נשמע (קהלת יב). **ועתה ישראל מה ה' אלהיך שואל מעמך כי אם ליראה וגו'** (דברים י). מאד מאד הוי שפל רוח. וכיוצא באלה הרגל על לשונך ואז לא תכשל.

> Always accustom your lips (to) words of the fear of Heaven such as, "Be strong as a leopard, [" (M. Avot 5:24); "The end of the matter, when all is said and done: [Fear God and keep His commandments]," (Eccl. 12:13); "And now, Israel, what does the Lord your God require of you but to fear [the Lord your God]," (Deut. 10:12); "Be very, very humble," (M. Avot 4:4). And such as come out like these, accustom your language, and you shall not come to grief

The Artscroll Siddur brings a Sefer Yereim that says to say both of these parshios each day. I haven’t been able to find it inside though.

Comment: [A followup question.](/q/130859)