# Where is this Yereim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, repentance-teshuvah, yirat-shamaim

I see from [this question and answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130688/what-s-the-source-for-saying-parshyot-yirah-and-teshuva-daily?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C50.7332) that the Artscroll quotes a Yereim to say Parshas Hayirah and Hateshuva.

Does anyone know where this Yereim can be found?

Answer (score 5):

I checked the Siddur Otzar Hatefillos (page 231) on my shelf, which, instead of ספר יראים, reads ספרי יראים (with an extra yud). The latter can be translated as "the works of the [G-d-]fearing," and it is used in this context in Mussar literature (as evidenced by a Google Search turning up results from sefarim like Shivchei Habesh"t).

Adding to this that I searched for passages in Sefer Yere'im with a number of keywords (teshuvah, kol yom, etc.) and found nothing, **it seems very likely that Artscroll simply made an error here, and that there is no such passage in Sefer Yere'im**.